# Android Studio showing KVM error though KVM is installed in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, kvm

I am running android studio on Elementry OS. I have installed kvm and it's properly installed...see below screenshot...[image: KVM Test...]

but when i try to run emulator in android studio it's giving me following error...

[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: enable your system vertualiazation

Comment: i have no idea about how to do that...

Comment: see my below answer hope it may help you!!!

Comment: and one more thing, please ensure that your system does support Virtualization or not?? if not then you cant access it, so you should find other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to enable Virtualization**:

1. Power on the machine and open the BIOS.
2. Open the Processor submenu The processor settings menu may be hidden in the Chipset, Advanced CPU Configuration or Northbridge.
3. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT) or AMD-V depending on the brand of the processor.

for more hints watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Br2LzbBFOY)

Comment: tnx for the answer....to do this i need to talk to the higher authority since i have no permission to alter BIOS....hope this work....

Comment: in my office pc, intel virtualization technology is enabled...though i am getting this error...but it's working in my home pc...any other solution? plz,help....